# Obtain the R^2 of just the top predictors identified in a LASSO/ L1 penalized regression model

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, regularization, r-squared

I've developed a model using L1 penalized regression using tidymodels and 10-fold cross-validation, and determined the predictors that explain approximately 87% of the variance in test data. I need the penalization to scale unimportant predictors to zero. In the field, however, the top predictor is assumed to be much more overshadowing than what I have seen, so I would like to report the R² of a model with just the top predictors.

I can obtain an R² of the main predictors separately by comparing the prediction of a simple linear model with just the predictors of concern included to the true measurements in the test set.

But can I assume then that the R² of that much simpler model then actually be comparable to the penalized regression?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "comparable"?

Comment: Why not directly using the penalized model as the final one?

Comment: @MichaelM Yes, that would be prefarable, but how would I then get an R² estimate of a model with just the top predictor or the top five predictors?

Comment: @whuber I guess I mean comparable in the sense that if I would iteratively add predictors to a linear model in order of importance, as identified in the penalized linear model, the R² of the linear model would approach the R² or the original (penalized) model.

Comment: But that's mathematically guaranteed and thereby is no criterion at all!

Comment: Thank you for that! @whuber